# how to do Group By between three or more tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have **First Table** called Header

```
 id | user_id | created_on
------------------------
 15 |  42     | 1 day ago
 16 |  43     | 1 day ago
 17 |  44     | 1 day ago
 18 |  45     | 2 day ago
```

**Second Table** called Line

```
line_id | ph_name | quantity
----------------------------
 15     | nokia   | 3
 16     | sumsung | 5
 17     | nokia   | 1
```

**Third table** called User

```
 id | name
--------------
 42 |  hi
 43 |  bye
 44 |  tata
```

so how relate and group this to give out put like below based on the users count and by considering today date  in **SQL query** or **django aggregate ORM**

```
{
 {
   "ph_name":"nokia",
   "num_of_user":"2", //hi and tata are the users
   "quantity":"4"
 },
 {
   "ph_name":"samsung",
   "num_of_user":"1", //bye is the only user
   "quantity":"5"
 }
}
```

[image: this like i need to do]

Comment: omg.sql is easy???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ph_name, count(distinct first_table.user_id), sum(quantity)
from second_table 
inner join (select * from first_table where created_on = '1 day ago') as first_table on second_table.line_id = first_table.id
inner join third_table on third_table.id = first_table.user_id
group by ph_name
```

Pay attention, I don't know if your tables are in the same database/schema. You could have to specify the database/schema by prefixing table name by `schema/database_name.table_name`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173148/discussion-on-answer-by-barthelemy-pavy-how-to-do-group-by-between-three-or-more).